# Android TextView blur is strange

Tags: android

I blur TextView with code

```java
    rowTitle.setText("Some");
    rowTitle2.setText("(City)");
    //rowTitle.setText("Some title");
    //rowTitle2.setText("(City)");

    radius = rowTitle.getTextSize() / 3;
    filter = new BlurMaskFilter(radius, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
    rowTitle.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    rowTitle.getPaint().setMaskFilter(filter);
```

With text "Some"
[image]

With text "Some title"
[image]

1. Why blur not all text (pic1 and pic2)?
2. Why blur second TextView (pic2)?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya With LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE text not show. May be because I use android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

Answer (score 0):

All works good if remove

```xml
<TextView
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
/>
```